# Use of capture groups in String.split()

Tags: javascript, regex

```
$ node
> "ababaabab".split(/a{2}/)
[ 'abab', 'bab' ]
> "ababaabab".split(/(a){2}/)
[ 'abab', 'a', 'bab' ]
>
```

So, this doesn't make sense to me. Can someone explain it? I don't get why the `'a'` shows up.

Note: I am trying to match for doubled line endings (possibly on windows files) so I am splitting on `/(\r?\n){2}/`. However I get extraneous `'\015\n'` entries in my array (note `\015 == \r`).

Why are these showing up?

Note: also affects JS engine in browsers so this is specific to JS not node.

Comment: Interesting - same behavior in ruby too.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In your second result, `a` is appearing because you've wrapped it in a capture group `()` (parentheses).

If you want to *not* include it but you still require a conditional group, use a non-capturing group: `(?:a)`. The questionmark-colon can be used inside any capture group and it will be omitted from the resulting list of captures.

Here's a simple example of this in action: http://regex101.com/r/yM1vM4

Comment: Nail was hit on the head by @remus, thanks

Comment: `====[]  |--` I do that :)

Comment: Is the thing on the left the nail? I've never seen a square nail

Comment: No, that was my best-effort hammer ;) On the right is the nail.

Comment: Ah that makes more sense

Answer (score 11):

According to [ECMA](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.4.14):

> String.prototype.split (separator, limit)
>
> If *separator* is a regular expression that contains capturing parentheses, then each time *separator* is matched the results (including any **undefined** results) of the capturing parentheses are spliced into the output array.

The example given was:

```
"ababaabab".split(/(a){2}/) // [ "abab", "a", "bab" ]
```

The `split` occurs on `aa`, but only `"a"` is in the capturing group `(a)` so that is what is spliced into the output array.

More examples:

```
"ababaaxaabab".split(/(a){2}/) // ["abab", "a", "x", "a", "bab"]

"ababaaxaabab".split(/(aa)/) // ["abab", "aa", "x", "aa", "bab"]
```

Comment: In my opinion, this is a more helpful answer. It explains *why* the behavior is happening and where to read the official documentation.

Answer (score 3):

Because the {2} is outside the capturing brackets, I'm guessing it splits on 2 characters, but only captures the first.

If you move the {2} inside the brackets:

```
"ababaabab".split(/(a{2})/)
```

then you'll get

```
["abab", "aa", "bab"]
```

If you don't want the 'aa's, don't group it in brackets. i.e.

```
"ababaabab".split(/a{2}/)
```

Gives

```
["abab", "bab"]
```

Comment: `()` is capturing the last match, not first... as in `"ababazbab".split(/(a|z){2}/)` => `[..., "z", ...]`

Answer (score 2):

In regular expressions `()` denotes a capturing group.  To not capture it use a non-capturing group `(?:)`.

Comment: Still makes no sense that I would want to keep the group when I am splitting. But that's fine. `(?:)` it is.

Answer (score 1):

split keeps capturing groups. That's why you see it in the result.

Look at the description and capturing parentheses:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Comment: Use non-capturing group? `(?:)`

Comment: Yeah, that's a `d'oh` moment.