# JavaScript URL regex splitting

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a Regex that is able to detect URLs (Disclosure: I copied this Regex from the internet).

My goal is to split a string, so that I get an array of substrings that either are a full URL or not.

For example.

```
const detectUrls = // some magical Regex
const input = 'Here is a URL: https://google.com <- That was the URL to Google.';

console.log(input.split(detectUrls)); // This should output ['Here is a URL: ', 'https://google.com', ' <- That was the URL to Google.']
```

My current Regex solution is as follows: `/(([a-z]+:\/\/)?(([a-z0-9\-]+\.)+([a-z]{2}|aero|arpa|biz|com|coop|edu|gov|info|int|jobs|mil|museum|name|nato|net|org|pro|travel|local|internal))(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/[a-z0-9_\-.~]+)*(\/([a-z0-9_\-.]*)(\?[a-z0-9+_\-.%=&amp;]*)?)?(#[a-zA-Z0-9!$&'()*+.=-_~:@/?]*)?)(\s+|$)/gi;`

However, when I run the example code with my regex, I get a useless answer:

```
[ 'Here is a URL: ', 
  'https://google.com', 
  'https://', 
  'google.com', 
  'google.', 
  'com', 
  undefined, 
  undefined, 
  undefined, 
  undefined, 
  undefined, 
  undefined, 
  ' ', 
  '<- That was the URL to Google.',
]
```

Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance.

Comment: In regex `(...)` is called a _capture group_. Your result array has one item for each capture group. A solution would be _named_ capture groups but browser support is probably bad (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367369/named-capturing-groups-in-javascript-regex). Instead of writing your own solution why not re-use an existing one? (https://www.google.com/search?q=js+url+extractor&oq=js+url+extractor&aqs=chrome..69i57.2193j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 2):

The reason why you are getting multiple matches is that the regex will return a match for each of your groups (the things inside parentheses).
For the result you want you should be using non capture groups `(?:myRegex)`
I modified your regex so that it should work:

```
/((?:[a-z]+:\/\/)?(?:(?:[a-z0-9\-]+\.)+(?:[a-z]{2}|aero|arpa|biz|com|coop|edu|gov|info|int|jobs|mil|museum|name|nato|net|org|pro|travel|local|internal))(?::[0-9]{1,5})?(?:\/[a-z0-9_\-.~]+)*(?:\/(?:[a-z0-9_\-.]*)(?:\?[a-z0-9+_\-.%=&amp;]*)?)?(?:#[a-zA-Z0-9!$&'(?:)*+.=-_~:@/?]*)?)(?:\s+|$)/
```

Tip: use an online website like https://regex101.com/ to test your regular expressions.
Also the answer for this question helped a bit:
[Use of capture groups in String.split()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21419530/use-of-capture-groups-in-string-split)

Comment: Thanks for your answer and for linking to other resources that I can learn from. Your answer fixes my issue!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var detectUrls = /(([a-z]+:\/\/)?(([a-z0-9\-]+\.)+([a-z]{2}|aero|arpa|biz|com|coop|edu|gov|info|int|jobs|mil|museum|name|nato|net|org|pro|travel|local|internal))(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/[a-z0-9_\-.~]+)*(\/([a-z0-9_\-.]*)(\?[a-z0-9+_\-.%=&amp;]*)?)?(#[a-zA-Z0-9!$&'()*+.=-_~:@/?]*)?)(\s+|$)/gi;

var input = "Here is a URL: https://google.com";

alert(input.match(detectUrls));
```

Working Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/as2pbe3m/

Comment: It's just matching the pattern, OP wants an array with the string split using URL.