# Regex get only full matching (Not grouping)

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex which looks like this:

```
[@|#](.*?)\s
```

What I basically want is, split matching regex into arrays.

So I use the following code:

```
var testString = "Hi this is a test @info@test.com and @martin we have to go."
console.log(testString.split(/(\@|\#)(.*?)\s/));
```

The result what I get looks like this:

```
["Hi this is a test ", "@", "info@test.com", "and ", "@", "martin", "we have to go."]
```

What I actually want is:

```
["Hi this is a test ", "@info@test.com", "and ", "@martin", "we have to go."]
```

https://regex101.com/r/yJf9gU/1

https://jsfiddle.net/xy4bgtmn/

Comment: didnt know that the pope does coding

Comment: Please see [Use of capture groups in String.split()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21419530/4642212).

Comment: If you need `@info@test.com` into your array then `split` is not for you. `Split` doesn't include the `separator` into the resulting array.

Comment: Can someone edit the title? my wording is bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `split`, use `match`:

```js
testString.match(/[@#]\S+|[^@#]+/g)
// ["Hi this is a test ", "@info@test.com", " and ", "@martin", " we have to go."]
```

This regex simply matches all non-spaces after an `@` or a `#`, or it matches all non-`@` or `#` characters, effectively splitting it into chunks.

Answer (score 2):

You could use split by placing `[#@]` inside the capture group followed by matching 1+ non whitespace chars  `([#@]\S+)`

```js
let s = "Hi this is a test @info@test.com and @martin we have to go.";
console.log(s.split(/([#@]\S+)/));
```