# Regexp to explode url

Tags: javascript, url, split

I have a string url like `"home/products/product_name_1/details/some_options"`
And i want to parse it into array with Regexp to `["home", "products","product","details","some"]`

So the rule is "split by words if backslash, but if the word have underscores - take only that part that comes before first underscore"

JavaScript equivalent for this regex is

```
str.split("/").map(item => item.indexOf("_") > -1 ? item.split("_")[0] : item)
```

Please help!

Comment: What is your regex tool or language?  We need to know this in order to be able to help you here.

Comment: To rephrase your question in URL-specific terms: You want to split the given URL into its _path-segments_ or more generic: _URL normalization_. Did you search here like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=path%20segments%20from%20URL) ? What did you try ? Please post (any code) as example.

Comment: Currently im using JavaScript. But i want to do this with regexp, instead something like str.split("/").map(item => item.indexOf("\_") > 0 ? item.split("_")[0] : item)

Comment: Correct. "name", "1", "options" are ignoring

Comment: You already have a working solution. Is there any reasons why you would switch to RegEx? If you can't write such pattern, you won't be able to maintain it.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this pattern

```
(?<!\w)[^/_]+
```

results

```
['home', 'products', 'product', 'details', 'some']
```

python code

```
import re
str="home/products/product_name_1/details/some_options"

re.findall('(?<!\w)[^/_]+',str)

['home', 'products', 'product', 'details', 'some']
```

Answer (score 1):

Given input:

- string `"home/products/product_name_1/details/some_options"`

Expected output:

- array `["home", "products", "product", "details", "some"]`
- Note: ignore/exclude `name`, `1`, `options` (because word occurs after 1st underscore).

Task:

- **split** [URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#syntax) by slash into a set of *path-segments* (words)
- (if the path-segment or word contains underscores) **remove** the part after first underscore

### Regex to match

With a regex `\/|_\w+` you could match the *URL-path separator* (slash) and *excluded word-part* (every word after an underscore).

Then use this regex

- either as *separator* to split the string into its parts（excluding the regex matches): e.g. in JS `split(/\/|_\w+/)`
- or as search-pattern in replace to prepare a string that can be easily split: e.g. in JS `replaceAll(/\/|_\w+/g, ',')` to obtain a CSV row which can be easily split by comma `split(',')

Beware: The regular-expression itself (flavor) and functions to apply it depend on your environment/regex-engine and script-/programming-language.

### Regex  applied in Javascript

#### split by regex

For example in Javascript use `url.split(/\/|_\w*/)` where:

- `/pattern/`:  everything inside the slashes is the regex-pattern
- `\/`: a c slash (URL-path-separator)
- `|`: the alternate junction, interpreted as boolean OR
- `_\w*`: zero or more (`*`) word-characters (`w`, i.e. letter from alphabet, numeric digit or underscore) following an underscore

See also:

- [Use of capture groups in String.split()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21419530/use-of-capture-groups-in-string-split)

However, this returns also empty strings (as empty split-off second parts inside underscore-containing path-segments). We can remove the empty strings with a `filter` where predicate `s => s` returns true if the string is non-empty.

Demo to solve your task:

```js
const url = "home/products/product_name_1/details/some_options";

let firstWordsInSegments = url.split(/\/|_\w*/).filter(s => s);

console.log(firstWordsInSegments);


const urlDuplicate = "home/products/product_name_1/details/some_options/_/home";
console.log(urlDuplicate.split(/\/|_\w*/).filter(s => s)); // contains duplicates in output array
```

#### replace into CSV, then split and exclude (map,replace,filter)

The CSV containing path-segments can be split by comma and resulting parts (path-segments) can be filtered or replaced to exclude unwanted sub-parts.

using:

- [`replaceAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll) to transform to CSV or remove empty strings. Note: global flag required when calling replaceAll with regex
- `map` to remove unwanted parts after underscore
- `filter(s => s)` to filter out empty strings

```js
const url = "home/products/product_name_1/details/some_options";

// step by step
let pathSegments = url.split('/');
console.log('pathSegments:', pathSegments);
let firstWordsInSegments = pathSegments.map(s => s.replaceAll(/_\w*/g,''));
console.log(firstWordsInSegments);

// replace to obtain CSV and then split
let csv = "home/products/product_name_1/details/some_options/_/home".replaceAll(/\/|_\w+/g, ',');
console.log('csv:', csv);
let parts = csv.split(',');
console.log('parts:', parts); // contains empty parts
let nonEmptyParts = parts.filter(s => s);
console.log('nonEmptyParts:', nonEmptyParts); // filtered out empty parts
```

### Bonus Tip

Try your regex online (e.g. regex101 or regexplanet). See the [demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/6ifQHw/1).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
input = ["home/products/product_name_1/details/some_options",
    "company/products/cars_all/details/black_color",
    "public/places/1_cities/disctricts/1234_something"]

let pattern = /([a-zA-Z\d]*)(?:\/|_.*?(?:\/|$))/gmi

input.forEach(el => {
    let matches = el.matchAll(pattern)
    for (const match of matches) {
        console.log(match[1]);
    }
})
```

Remove `\d` from the regex pattern if you dont want digits in the url.
I have used matchAll here, matchAll returns a iterator, use that to get each match object, inside which the first element is the full match, and the second elemnt(index: `1`) is the required group.

```
/([a-zA-Z\d]*)(?:\/|_.*?(?:\/|$))/gmi

/
([a-zA-Z\d]*)         capture group to match letters and digits
(?:\/|_.*?(?:\/|$))   non capture group to match '/' or '_' and everything till another '/' or end of the line is found 
/gmi
```

You can test this regex here: https://regex101.com/r/B5Bo74/1

Comment: If you are using the `/i` flag you can shorten the character class to `[a-z\d]+` and repeat it 1 or more times to prevent matching an empty string. You might turn the first alternation in an optional group and the non greedy dot `.*?` into a negated character class `let pattern = /([a-z\d]+)(?:_[^\/\n]*)?(?:\/|$)/gmi`

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
\b[^\W_]+
```

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial match
- `[^\W_]+` Match 1+ word characters except for `_`

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tbkDQh/1).

```js
const s = "home/products/product_name_1/details/some_options";
const regex = /\b[^\W_]+/g;
console.log(s.match(regex));
```

If there has to be a leading `/` or the start of the string before the match, you can use an alternation `(?:^|\/)` and use a capture group for the values that you want to keep:

```js
const s = "home/products/product_name_1/details/some_options";
const regex = /(?:^|\/)([^\W_]+)/g;
console.log(Array.from(s.matchAll(regex), m => m[1]));
```

Comment: Great simple regex to split words. The use of word-boundaries makes it reusable and more versatile - to split more than just URIs.

Answer (score 0):

You could split the url with this regex

```
(_\w*)+|(\/)
```

This matches the /, _name_1 and _options.

BUT depending what you are trying to to, or which language do you use, there are way better options to do this.

Comment: `split` will keep the values of the capture groups. You can omit the groups and remove the emtpy entries `s.split(/_\w*|\//).filter(Boolean)`

Answer (score 0):

You can try a pattern like `\/([^\/_]+){1,}` (assuming that the path starts with '/' and the components are separated by '/'); depending on language you might get an array or iterator that will give the components.

Comment: The pattern will not match `home` as it is not preceded by `/`

Answer (score 0):

Try `^[[:alpha:]]+|(?<=\/)[[:alpha:]]+`  or `^[a-zA-Z]+|(?<=\/)[a-zA-Z]+` if [[:alpha:]] is not supported , it matches one or more characters on the beginning or after slash until first non char.

Comment: I think posix expressions like `[:alpha:]` are not supported in Javascript.